# Change color when I finish to take notes in every point every week

Tags: symbology, qfield, color, forest-ecology

During the collection data on field (ecology and phenology data) on different days I would like to change the color of symbol when I finish to take notes in every point in a concret day.
How it would be possible to do this action ???

1. I arrive to point
2. I take ecology data notes
3. I select the 'DONE' mark (the point changes the color)
   ¿and the next field journey?

Answer (score 0):

Use 'Catergorized ' symbology on the attribute that gets marked 'DONE'.

A more detailed answer requires a more detailed question.